# Calculate timestamp difference between two columns in a dataframe and add a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe,

df1 =

```
Load      sort_begin                              comp_begin            
a         Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024             -                      


b        Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024            Mon Jan 15 23:23:58 PST 2024 

c        Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024            Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024
```

Basically, I have multiple stages like sort_begin, comp_begin. It starts with sort_begin at Load a, and advances to Comp_begin at load 2 and so on.

How can I compute the time elapsed between sort_begin to comp_begin in seconds and add a new column to the end like below

```
 Load      sort_begin                              comp_begin                        diff
    a         Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024             -                      
    
    
    b        Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024            Mon Jan 15 23:23:58 PST 2024     xx
    
    c        Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024            Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024     xx
```

Time stamps are in above format : Mon Jan xx:xx:xx PST 2024. We are only interested in actual time difference b/w stages ( sort_begin , comp_begin ).